# aws Property validation failure for a ONTAP volume creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to Create AWS FSxN(ONTAP) Volume via `Cloudformation` where I'm using `Parameters` also while executing the template `stack` it failing with an error as given below.

Being a novice I'm not able to catch the issue, any help or hint Would be much appreciated.

[cloudformation](/questions/tagged/cloudformation) template below:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: >
  Description: "AWS CloudFormation to create multiple ONTAP volumes.

Parameters:
  VolumeName1:
    Type: String
    Description: 'The name of the first volume.'
    Default: 'testVol001'
  Volume1Size:
    Description: 'The size of the first volume.'
    Type: Number
    Default: 100
  VolumeName2:
    Type: String
    Description: 'The name of the Second volume.'
    Default: 'testVol002'
  Volume2Size:
    Type: Number
    Description: 'The size of the first volume.'
    Default: '100'
  SVMName:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Provide the name of the backup-plan'
    Default: 'svm-0524816479dbbe473'
  FSxVolType:
    Type: String
    Description: 'FSx Volume Type'
    Default: 'ONTAP'
    
Resources:
  VolumeName:
    Type: "AWS::FSx::Volume"
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref VolumeName1
      OntapConfiguration:
        -
          JunctionPath: !Ref VolumeName1
          SizeInMegabytes: !Ref Volume1Size
          StorageEfficiencyEnabled: true
          StorageVirtualMachineId: !Ref SVMName
          VolumeType: !Ref FSxVolType
      Tags:
      - Key: "archival"
        Value: "backup"
        
  VolumeName:
    Type: "AWS::FSx::Volume"
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref VolumeName2
      OntapConfiguration:
        -
          JunctionPath: !Ref VolumeName2
          SizeInMegabytes: !Ref Volume2Size
          StorageEfficiencyEnabled: true
          StorageVirtualMachineId: !Ref SVMName
          VolumeType: !Ref FSxVolType
      Tags:
      - Key: "archival"
        Value: "backup"
...
```

**Error:**

```
2022-08-03 21:52:24 UTC+0530    VolumeName  CREATE_FAILED   Property validation failure: [Value of property {/OntapConfiguration} does not match type {Object}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using substitute `!Sub` to substitute the `Parameter` or `Variable` in the template you need to specify template `parameter names` or `resource logical IDs`, such with clode curly parenthesis and a doller sign as `${}`, you also need to correct the `indentation` and remove the `-` .

More information can be found on the AWS documentation [AWS Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html)

Please try Below its working ...

```
---
Description: "This is Cloudformation template for Creating Multiple Volumes While using parameters."
Parameters:
  FSxSVMiD:
    Default: svm-0524816479dbbe473
    Description: "Provide the SVM Name for FSxN"
    Type: String
  FSxVolType:
    Default: 'ONTAP'
    Type: String
  FSxVolume01:
    Default: DemoFSxVolume01
    Description: "This is First Volume in the template Selection"
    Type: String
  FSxVolume02:
    Default: DemoFsxVolume02
    Description: "This is Second Volume in the template Selection"
    Type: String
  FSxVolumeSize:
    Default: 1024
    Type: Number
Resources:
  AWSDemoVolume1:
    Description: "This is a Demo Volume resource"
    Type: 'AWS::FSx::Volume'
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref FSxVolume01
      OntapConfiguration:
        JunctionPath: !Sub "/${FSxVolume01}"
        SizeInMegabytes: !Ref FSxVolumeSize
        StorageEfficiencyEnabled: true
        StorageVirtualMachineId: !Ref FSxSVMiD
      VolumeType: !Ref FSxVolType
      Tags:
        - Key: "backup"
          Value: "archival"
  AWSDemoVolume2:
    Description: "This is a Demo Volume resource"
    Type: 'AWS::FSx::Volume'
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref FSxVolume02
      OntapConfiguration:
        JunctionPath: !Sub "/${FSxVolume02}"
        SizeInMegabytes: !Ref FSxVolumeSize
        StorageEfficiencyEnabled: true
        StorageVirtualMachineId: !Ref FSxSVMiD
      VolumeType: !Ref FSxVolType
      Tags:
        - Key: "backup"
          Value: "archival"
```